# jQuery Easing Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an Unordered List setup, I would like to apply the simple elastic property used in jQuery. When running the script, I keep getting an JavaScript Error :

> Error: D.easing[this.options.easing || (D.easing.swing ? "swing" : "linear")] is not a function
>   Source File: jquery-pack.js?1296815924

The Java is working but it is not creating the desired effect. My jQuery Code is :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

 //When mouse rolls over
$("li").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height:'50px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: "easeOutElastic"})
});

$("li").mouseout(function(){
$(this).stop().animate({height:'50px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: "easeInBounce"})
});

     }); 
</script>
```

I had taken this script from a tutorial, so would have expected it to work. It seems that the easing is not being passed from page to the script?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `easeOutElastic` and `easeInBounce` easing functions are defined by the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Effects/Methods) plugin, not by the core jQuery framework.

You'll have to include that plugin in your page.

Comment: Hmm, I am referencing : <script src="jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script> Is that the correct plugin?

Comment: @StuBlackett, that's indeed the right plugin, so it should work. Can you dump `jQuery.easing` to the console and check that the easing functions are properly registered?

Comment: Its saying : >>> jQuery.easing
Object {} I'm not convinced that the library is loaded.

Comment: The net tab in my FireBug is saying that the library has loaded in

Comment: @StuBlackett, maybe something else is messing with that object. Do you load any other plugins?

Comment: Thats the issue, I think there is another jQuery Library loading in. There is a line of script to load multiple libraries?

Comment: @Stu, I'm afraid I don't understand your previous comment :)

Comment: There is a no conflict script, to prevent multiple loading of libraries, I will try that

Answer (score 2):

You have to include an easing library like this one: **http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/**

@Frédéric Hamidi No need for the whole jQuery UI there...

Comment: Hi Capsule. I have referenced the jquery.easing.1.3 script in my page.

Comment: In the headers of my page are : script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>